# Fill HTML "element" + part of ":before element" with same color or image in pure CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a service that will be load in front of a video. Here is some basic code that shows the main shape of the service : [CodePen link](https://codepen.io/mleger06/pen/qeVwRB)

Here is the code :

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidezone">
    <div class="header">
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <div class="tab_elt active_tab">Tab 1</div>
      <div class="tab_elt">Tab 2</div>
      <div class="tab_elt">Tab 3</div>
      <div class="tab_elt">Tab 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 1280;
  height: 720px;
  margin: auto 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
.sidezone {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  top: 0; right: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 720px;
  padding: 26px 52px 26px 16px;
}
.sidezone:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: -50px; bottom: 0;

  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 0px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 720px solid transparent; 
  border-right: 50px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.header {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: o-HelveticaNeue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/550/200/sports");
  background-position: center top;
}

.tab {
  background: #000;
}
.tab_elt {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px 0;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}
.active_tab {
  color: #f16e00;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f16e00;
}

.content {
  height: 419px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

My question is : **How can I "fill" the "sidezone" part from the top to the bottom of my "tab" part with a color or a picture in pure CSS ?**

I'd like to make something that looks more "natural" but now I feel like my header is just "stick" in my block...

I tried to make it work by cutting my ":before" element in two part : one that could be black as my tab (and my header if I remove the image) that will go from top to the bottom of the "tab", and an other that will start just after and go to the bottom. This way I could keep my current shape and have 2 differents color to do what i want, but can't achieve it...

I insist on the "pure CSS" (no SVG, no lib,...), I'm very limited in possibilities.

**Is it possible ?**

---

**Edit** : here a visual representation of what I try to achieve (sorry for my paint talent !)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change the borders of your pseudo element to these:

```
  border-top: 294px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

You may have to adjust the border widths. But the idea is to draw a trapezium/trapezoid using the borders.

Then remove the background color on your `sidezone` and replace it with this:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 294px, transparent 294px);
```

Again, you can change the dimensions as you see fit.

See here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OKzWrN

Comment: This is almost what I try to achieve, but the sidezone must keep the background color and now I don't have the bottom part of my before element ! Will try to work with that a little, thanks

Comment: @MickaëlLeger let me know what I am missing and I can try help in my free time

Comment: I posted my answer, you helped me to do the first part that I wanted and I manage to finish it adding an :after element and changing some color :) And a coworker helped me to do it with a picture, you can check it bellow if you want. Thanks, I give your the +1 for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a background gradient?
Like this:

background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(246,41,12,1) 66%, rgba(240,47,23,1) 71%, rgba(231,56,39,1) 100%);

Comment: I edit my question with a picture, hope it's more clear :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this refers to what you were asking, but if you set one of the border-sides to a large size and solid color such as `border-top: 10px solid blue;`, then that could mimic the behavior that you are wanting.

EDIT: (I'm still not totally sure of what you are asking) I would create a div for the side, fill the background, and then have any elements that are inside the div to have `background: transparent;`. In my opinion, you should try not to use the `::before` selector, as it might be difficult to tell where it actually goes.

Comment: I edit my question with a picture, hope it's more clear :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Frank Fajardo I manage to achieve what I wanted : https://codepen.io/mleger06/pen/WVddVg

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidezone">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="tab">
      <div class="tab_elt active_tab">Tab 1</div>
      <div class="tab_elt">Tab 2</div>
      <div class="tab_elt">Tab 3</div>
      <div class="tab_elt">Tab 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 1280;
  height: 720px;
  margin: auto 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
.sidezone {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000 294px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 294px);
  top: 0; right: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 720px;
  padding: 26px 52px 26px 16px;
}
.sidezone:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: -50px; bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 294px solid #000;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid #000;
}
.sidezone:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 294px; left: -30px; bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 426px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.header {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: o-HelveticaNeue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 200px;
}

.tab {
  background: #000;
}
.tab_elt {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px 0;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}
.active_tab {
  color: #f16e00;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f16e00;
}

.content {
  height: 419px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

I change the color a little bit and add a `:after` element in CSS to fill the bottom part and keep the same shape of the left of my `sidezone`.

Thanks for helping !

---

**Edit** : here is an other result by a collegue with an other "tricks" to make it works with image : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zgpjRQ